# Omitting certain character from being output in a random password generator program

Tags: python, random, module, character, ascii

I'm writing a program that randomly generates a combination of any amount of ASCII characters.

```
import random
import string

string.printable
sP = string.printable

def random_pass(stringLength):
     x = sP
     return ''.join((random.choice(x)) for i in range(stringLength))
     if x == '<0x0c>' or '<0x0b>:
     print("Try again!")
print('You'\re password is: ', random_pass(12))
```

- What do `<0x0c>` and `<0x0b>` stand for?
- During some iterations of the program, these character codes are printed out.
- Do they represent white space?
- My if statement in the random_pass() function doesn't omit the character codes from appearing in the output. Which is why I now seek help.

Answer (score 0):

According to Python documentation on [common strings operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.printable):

> **string.printable**
>
> String of characters which are considered printable. This is a combination of digits, letters, punctuation, and whitespace.

and whitespace is defined as:

> **string.whitespace**
>
> A string containing all characters that are considered whitespace. On most systems this includes the characters space, tab, linefeed,
>   return, formfeed, and vertical tab.

So that is normal to have sometimes those characters in the `random.choice(x)`

- 0x0c is linefeed
- 0x0b is vertical tab

You should probably not use `string.printable` but instead something like `string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation`

Answer (score 0):

> What do <0x0c> and <0x0b> stand for?
>
> During some iterations of the program, these character codes are printed out.

- `0x0c` is linefeed
- `0x0b` is vertical tab

you can look them up in an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

> Do they represent white space?

yes, they are part of [`string.whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#string.whitespace)

> My if statement in the random_pass() function doesn't omit the character codes from appearing in the output. Which is why I now seek help.

Your condition to check for `0x0c` and `0x0b` is never executed since it is placed after the `return` statement of `random_pass`.

As already suggested by @Tigre-Bleu you should use `string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation` instead of `string.printable`

Also, you should use a **cryptographically strong random number generator** when generating passwords. If you use Python >= 3.6 you can use the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module:

```
import secrets
import string

def random_pass(stringLength):
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(stringLength))
    return password

print('Your password is:', random_pass(12))
# Your password is: 2;=1!*A.dK;+
```

for Python < 3.6 you can use [`random.SystemRandom()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) which will use [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom) on systems which support it:

```
import random
import string

def random_pass(stringLength):
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    password = ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(alphabet) for i in range(stringLength))
    return password

print 'Your password is:', random_pass(12)
# Your password is: V9I:+H{_>*'p
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I noticed a few suggestions online detailing the use of a cryptographically  strong random number generator. Why is this suggested?

Comment: A requirement for a CSPRNG is that an adversary not knowing the seed has only negligible advantage in distinguishing the generator's output sequence from a random sequence.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: Ehhh I'm sorry. This is all gibberish to me, I really don't understand: adversary, seed,  etc. Does this have to with "encryption"? Basically, any pseudorandom number generator needs to be encrypted or something?

Comment: For the password generator this means that a bad guy (the adversary) has it more difficult to guess the passwords that were generated. The same applies for encryption which also relies on random numbers.